# ExceptionConsumeContext filter in MassTransit

Tags: exception, serilog, masstransit

in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518324/mastransit-with-serilog/70567305#70567305)  I found it that how to send my Serilog enrichment properties to consumers. when I logging my informations, then every thing is correct. but when throws an exception in the consumers, I don't see my Serilog properties in the log file. as you can see:

> ERR -  -  -

```
2022-01-03 12:25:40.346 - myApp - MassTransit.ReceiveTransport - ERR -  -  -  => R-FAULT "rabbitmq://localhost/MyConsumer" "c8100000-568d-0050-407a-08d9ce96c99c"
```

well, I guess the exception logging occurred in another context. I guess the exception logging occurred in the ExceptionConsumeContext class.
well I Implemented a filter for ExceptionConsumeContext:

```
public class IntegrationEventExceptionConsumeFilter<T> : IFilter<ExceptionConsumeContext <T>> where T : class {
public IntegrationEventPublishFilter()
{
  
}

public Task Send(ExceptionConsumeContext <T> context, IPipe<ExceptionConsumeContext <T>> next)
{    
    return next.Send(context);
}

public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
{
}}
```

now I need to add this filter to MassTransit configuration:

```
  cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(IntegrationEventExceptionConsumeFilter<>), context);
```

well, I got the exception:

```
The scoped filter must implement GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<MyEvent>>  (Parameter 'scopedType')
```

well, I couldn't find any conumer filter registeration for type of ExceptionConsumeContext.
and Since the I saw ExceptionConsumeContext inherited from ConsumeContext, I guess can be register this filter as a ConsumeFilter!. but don't work this way.

```
public interface ExceptionConsumeContext : ConsumeContext, PipeContext, MessageContext, IPublishEndpoint, IPublishObserverConnector, ISendEndpointProvider, ISendObserverConnector{}
```

now, I don't know what I do!

Answer (score -1):

There is no scoped filter registration for `ExceptionConsumeContext`. You would need to *add* your additional filter to the receive pipeline.

```cs
 cfg.ConfigureError(x =>
{
    x.UseFilter(new GenerateFaultFilter());
    x.UseFilter(new IntegrationEventExceptionConsumeFilter());
    x.UseFilter(new ErrorTransportFilter());
});
```

Note that there is no message-specific generic version of `ExceptionConsumeContext`.

Comment: I want to apply the filter to all consumers(endpoints), then I wrote below code . but didn't work. don't find and run my filter when throws an exception. cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(c => c.ConfigureError(x =>
{
    x.UseFilter(new GenerateFaultFilter());
    x.UseFilter(new MyFilter());
    x.UseFilter(new ErrorTransportFilter());
});
    )

Comment: You'd have to add it to the actual receive endpoints, not create a new one. Using maybe something like this: https://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.1.6.html#iconfigurereceiveendpoint

Comment: thanks, yes I wrote IConfigureReceiveEndpoint, and now ran my filter. but before ran my filter(Send method of the IFilter), I saw my log file that wrote the exception, then my pushing Serilog properties in the my filter is not applied in the logging. maybe I must be push my properties in prior steps of the pipe?

Comment: my exception:  MassTransit.ReceiveTransport - ERR -  -  -  => R-FAULT rabbitmq://localhost/..."  System.Exception: test at ...MassTransit.Scoping.Filters.ScopedFilter`1.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
   at MassTransit.Scoping.Filters.ScopedFilter`1.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
   at MassTransit.Scoping.ScopeConsumerFactory`1.Send[TMessage](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
   at MassTransit.Scoping.ScopeConsumerFactory`1.Send[TMessage](...)    at  MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send

Comment: I doubt you're going to find what you need at this point.

Comment: well, I just want to push my properties to Serilog logging file when an exception throws into consumers. how can I do that? In above comment, as you can see, I sent a sample of log file that don't log my properties.